# No node found for selector, but selector is there on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am having some trouble trying to type text into an input field with Puppeteer. Here is the HTML for the website I am using, and it shows that the `id` of the field is `creditCardNumber`:

[image: HTML]

When I try to use `page.focus` and `page.type`, it say that there is no node for selector. Is this code wrong, or is there something better I can do?

```
await page.waitFor(1500);
await page.focus('#creditCardNumber');
await page.focus('#creditCardNumber', '1234', {delay: 5});
```

This is the error I get:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: #creditCardNumber

Answer (score 9):

DOM element might not be rendered at the time, when you trying to make a focus on it.

Try to use `page.waitForSelector` before the `page.focus` call:

```
await page.waitFor(1500);
await page.waitForSelector('#creditCardNumber');
await page.focus('#creditCardNumber');
await page.focus('#creditCardNumber', '1234', {delay: 5});
```

Comment: When I try that I get this error: TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#creditCardNumber" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Comment: That's means that your DOM element wasn't rendered or it inside of iFrame. 
For the iFrame you can find it with `page.frames`, and then call `frame.focus` on the iFrame element with your selector.

Comment: How would I go about that because I have tried and nothing is working?

Comment: If you tried both options, than your element probably wasn't rendered and you need to figure out why :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the `#creditCardNumber` element to be added to the DOM using [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options).

Since [you are receiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148140/no-node-found-for-selector-but-selector-is-there-on-html-page#comment93200778_53148318) a [`TimeoutError`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-timeouterror), you can extend (or even disable) the maximum navigation time using the `timeout` option:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#creditCardNumber', {timeout: 60000});
```

Also, it appears that you are attempting to type into the input field using [`page.focus()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagefocusselector), but you should be using [`page.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options) instead.

```
await page.type('#creditCardNumber', '1234', {delay: 5});
```

As a result, your new code should look something like this:

```
await page.waitForSelector('#creditCardNumber', {timeout: 60000});
await page.type('#creditCardNumber', '1234', {delay: 5});
```

Furthermore, you can also use [`elementHandle.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandletypetext-options) to simplify your code even more:

```
const credit_card_number = await page.waitForSelector('#creditCardNumber', {timeout: 60000});
await credit_card_number.type('1234', {delay: 5});
```

> **Note:** If you are still receiving a [`TimeoutError`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-timeouterror) after the above changes, you may want to inspect the [`page.content()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecontent) or take a screenshot of the page with [`page.screenshot()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) to verify that the page is returning the results that you are expecting.